# how to install python package inside pymol

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pymol

Is there a way to use setuptools inside a Python interpreter for installing a package? When you open PyMOL, there is a Python interpreter running so I thought I could use that one to install the packages since I cannot use the Python and sys.path inside PyMOL directory. What would you advise me?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(['install', 'packagename'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but there is no pip in PyMOL as it seems.

Comment: Try installing pip first. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows, I have Python installed already (with everything pip, setuptools etc.) but problem is PyMOL uses a different path and it has its own interpreter. So I cannot install pip as well when I am inside PyMOL.

Comment: I am using ubuntu and I was able to import pip (pip is installed in system scope) from inside pyMol. Did you install pyMol from an exe? Did you install it as an administrator?

Comment: I have the licensed version of PyMOL from Schrödinger and I installed it from exe. I did not build it from source, that's probably possible with open source version.

Comment: In fact, I can install a package outside PyMOL and it can be accessed inside PyMoL. Since you are a paying customer, you can get support from Schrodinger on this.

Answer (score 0):

One hack that worked for me if you want to use your 'external' i.e. non-pymol python virtual environment and packages therein *inside pymol* (ex. your pymol-extending scripts depend on them) is to add the libs in that environment to path on pymol startup. I.e.:

```py
# ~/.pymolrc
import sys
sys.path.append('~/dev/myvenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages')
run ~/dev/my_pymol_extensions.py    # depends on stuff installed in ~/dev/myvenv
```

It's certainly not what God intended but it works.